# Question about bound sequence and the limit

Tags: calculus

We were taught that the limit of the sequence exists if the sequence is monotone and bound.

I understand how to tell if a sequence is monotonic, but I don't understand what "being bound" means. How would you tell if a sequence is bounded?

Comment: Maybe you are referring to sequences?

Comment: sorry, yes i did

Comment: A sequence has an upper bound if there is a number $x$ such that $a_n\leq x$, a lower bound $y$ if $a_n\geq y$ forall $n$

Comment: The adjective is "bound**ed**", not "bound". "Bound" is a substantive name, and "to bound" is a verb (which, of course, has its simple past and its participle "bounded/bounded"). As in: "A bound is a thing that bounds a bounded sequence. A bounded sequence is bounded by its bounds".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This criteria (theorem) is known as [Monotonic Sequence Theorem for Convergence](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-monotonic-sequence-theorem-for-convergence) and there are not general rules to determine monotonicity and bounding of the sequence since it depends case by case.

Note that bounded means that $\exists m,M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall n$

$$m\le a_n \le M$$

A well known example is the sequence

$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$$

for which we can prove monoticity, notably that it is strictly increasing, and bounding since

$$2\le\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\le3$$

thus the limit exist and we know that it is the number $e$.

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify; does it have to be both upper and lower bounded in order to satisfy this theorem?

Comment: if it is increasing it suffices to prove that it is upper bounded and viceversa! Note talso that the bound is not necessarly equal to the limit. But if it is monotonic and a bound exists the limit exists. You are welcome! Bye